# Program to sample and upload data samples of a wave not working as intended

Tags: python, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, sampling

So I am using a raspberry pi 3b+ with a bitscope Micro BS05 to sample a wave off an oscilloscope wave function generator and upload it to a real-time database on google firebase in real time. I have written a code that samples the wave and uploads it to firebase as intended. However the values that get uploaded are all the same. I am sampling the wave at 12k samples per second. So the data is uploaded to firebase as a set of 12288 float values uploaded every second as a node.

Here is a pic of my Real-time database structure:

[image]

In short: My code, which is supposed to keep on sampling and uploading the samples of a wave, is instead sampling one part of it (probably the first part) and is sending that data to the database over and over again. Please suggest changes to my code so I can stop going in loops and be able to sample the whole wave. PFA my code. Thanks in advance

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
from bitlib import *
from bitscope import *
import pyrebase
import random
import time

BL_Open('USB:/dev/ttyUSB1',1)
scope = Scope('USB:/dev/ttyUSB1',1)

devices = scope.devices

BL_Select(BL_SELECT_DEVICE,0)
BL_Mode(BL_MODE_FAST)

devices[0].mode(BL_MODE_FAST)

BL_Intro(BL_ZERO)
BL_Delay(BL_ZERO)

BL_Rate(1000000)
BL_Size(100)
scope.tracer.configure(
rate=BL_MAX_RATE,
size=BL_Size,
pre_capture=BL_ZERO,
post_capture=BL_ZERO
)

BL_Select(BL_SELECT_CHANNEL,0)
BL_Select(BL_SELECT_SOURCE,BL_SOURCE_POD)
BL_Offset(BL_ZERO)
BL_Range(BL_Count(BL_COUNT_RANGE))

devices[0].channels[0].configure(
source=BL_SOURCE_POD,
offset=BL_ZERO,
range=BL_Count(BL_COUNT_RANGE)
)

BL_Enable(True)
devices[0].channels[0].enable()

BL_Trace(0.01,BL_SYNCHRONOUS)
scope.tracer.trace(0.01,BL_SYNCHRONOUS)
Data = BL_Acquire()
Data = devices[0].channels[0].acquire()
print(Data)

config = {
  "apiKey": "AIzaSyCWJoHbxs-LSGWZwXkkjdtuA9xxxxAzM",
  "authDomain": "pycharm-873262.firebaseapp.com",
  "databaseURL": "https://pycharm-823462-default-rtdb.asia-southeast1.firebasedatabase.app",
  "projectId": "pycharm-8723262",
  "storageBucket": "pycharm-823262.appspot.com",
  "messagingSenderId": "984822323076",
  "appId": "1:98482490076:web:6423232756ab05a88219"
}

firebase = pyrebase.initialize_app(config)
db = firebase.database()

while True:
    data = {
    " " : Data
    }
    db.child("Bits").push(data)
    db.update(data)
```

Bits is a child we're trying to create in the database.
PS: I have changed the config block so as to safeguard my database